# Adding first row by group for longitudinal data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, row, longitudinal

Here is the data frame looking like:

```
subject_ID  cd4_time0    other_time  cd4_other_time
1           12            0.5            462
1            12            1.0            140 
1            12            3.0           789
1            12           6.0            100
2            4            0.5            230
2            4            1.0            350
2            4            1.9            450
2            4            3.2            550
3         
3
..
```

A brief introduction of my data frame: more than 2k patients followed up years. 
I have one column of cd4 value in baseline and another column with repeated measurements of cd4 per patient. Now I would like to combine these two types of cd4 data according to subject_ID into one column for my analysis. The output should be like this:

```
subject_ID  cd4_time0    other_time  cd4_other_time
1            12             0.5            12
1            12             0.5            462
1            12             1.0            140 
1            12            3.0             789
1            12             6.0            100
2            4             0.5             4
2            4             0.5            230
2            4             1.0            350
2            4             1.9            450
2            4             3.2            550
3         
3
..
```

Any solutions based on R is welcome. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df1 %>% left_join(df2, by="subject_ID")`

Comment: @c0bra Many thanks for your reply. But I think you did not understand my question correctly or I did not put it in a clear way. The first df is my current data frame. I would like to add first rows to another column to make final version of data frame for my analysis, indicated as the second df above. Not combine these two df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you can use `group_by %>% do` to construct data frames for each group dynamically:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(subject_ID) %>% do ({
# extract and modify the first row
      firstRow <- .[1,]
      firstRow['cd4_other_time'] <- firstRow['cd4_time0']

# bind the first row with the sub data frame . represents a data frame with a unique subject_ID
      bind_rows(firstRow, .)
})

#Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#Groups: subject_ID [2]

#   subject_ID cd4_time0 other_time cd4_other_time
#        <int>     <int>      <dbl>          <int>
#1           1        12        0.5             12
#2           1        12        0.5            462
#3           1        12        1.0            140
#4           1        12        3.0            789
#5           1        12        6.0            100
#6           2         4        0.5              4
#7           2         4        0.5            230
#8           2         4        1.0            350
#9           2         4        1.9            450
#10          2         4        3.2            550
```